# How to get the text having without any Element using Selenium Web driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was having a hard time using Selenium web driver to find the text for the below scenario.

```
<td valign="top">
<br/>
<span class="deviceLabel">Server</span>
<br/>
<span class="deviceLabel">User Name:  </span>
Siva 
<br/>
<span class="deviceLabel">ID:  </span>
12323
```

How do I get the Text "Siva" and "12323" using Selenium webdriver ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say you were having a hard time doing this. This usually means you have at least tried **something**. Show us what you have tried so far and why that didn't work.

Comment: Which bindings (ie language) are you using?

Comment: @user2637888 is there any particular reason why those particular components you wish to interact with are not `elements`?

Comment: @ Mark Rowlands : Just I want to print the text for certain scenarios

Comment: @ Arran: I have tried the following: 
string Username = WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("xxxxxxxxxxxx")).Text;
Driver.LogEvent.Information("UserName is '" + Username + "'");   This shows only heading "User Name:" instead of value

Comment: @Arran :  And also i tried                                 IWebElement WebElement = WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("xxxxxxxxxx"));   
/// WebElement getting overall Frame Xpath    
IList<IWebElement> Username = WebElement.FindElements(By.XPath("html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td")).Text;
///Username getting the xpath of above mentioned code
int count = Username.Count;
This count returns only 3 and those are Server, User Name: , ID: 
It doesnt return the text which i needed

Comment: Why are you using XPath, what's wrong with `driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("deviceLabel"))`? ...also this is C#, not C++.  ...what are you intending to do? What `span` are you trying to get?

Comment: @Arran: Thanks for Reply. Actually I am using C# ONLY for this. I have tried to get 'siva' and '12323'. From this HTML "deviceLabel" class common for lot of span. so for i am using xpath to get and also i am new for selenium web driver.

Comment: @Siva: When you respond to comments, it's more useful if you edit the question to add the new information. That way, anybody reading the question can see all the information at once, instead of having to read through all the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Use below `xpath` to find the required text

```
String Find_Shiva = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//Span[text()='User Name:  ']")).getText();

String find_12323= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//Span[text()='ID:  ']")).getText();
```